# Node js, NVD3.js cannot read property baseval of undefined

Tags: node.js, d3.js, nvd3.js

For the following data,

```
historicalBarChart = [ 
  {
    key: "Cumulative Return",
    values: [
      { 
        "label" : "A" ,
        "value" : 29.765957771107
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "B" , 
        "value" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "C" , 
        "value" : 32.807804682612
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "D" , 
        "value" : 196.45946739256
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "E" ,
        "value" : 0.19434030906893
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "F" , 
        "value" : 98.079782601442
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "G" , 
        "value" : 13.925743130903
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "H" , 
        "value" : 5.1387322875705
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I am going to generate Bar chart using NVD3.js with Node js server.

My Nodejs code to generate svg :
** NVD3svgnode.js **

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom'),
    child_proc = require('child_process'),
    w = 400,
    h = 400,          
    scripts = ["file://"+__dirname+"/d3.min.js",
               "file://"+__dirname+"/d3.layout.min.js",
                "file://"+__dirname+"/nv.d3.min.js",
               "file://"+__dirname+"/bar.js"],

    htmlStub = '<!DOCTYPE html><div id="bar" style="width:'+w+'px;height:'+h+'px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"></svg></div>';

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
           res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml'});
           jsdom.env({features:{QuerySelector:true}, html:htmlStub, scripts:scripts,   done:function(errors, window) {
                var chart1= window.bar();

       d3.select('#bar svg')
         .datum(historicalBarChart)
         .transition().duration(500)
         .call(chart1);
          }});
}).listen(8888);
```

My NVD3 code to generate bar is:
**bar.js**

```
function bar(){
var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .staggerLabels(true)
      .tooltips(false)
      .showValues(true);
return chart;
}
```

While executing the node js NVD3svgnode.js, i am getting the following exception

```
    file:///Users/administrator/Downloads/nodejs/d3.js:5347
        var t = g.transform.baseVal.consolidate();
                           ^
**strong text**TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined
    at d3.transform (file:///Users/administrator/Downloads/nodejs/d3.js:5347:28)
    at Object.d3.transform (file:///Users/administrator/Downloads/nodejs/d3.js:5350:7)
    at d3_interpolateTransform (file:///Users/administrator/Downloads/nodejs/d3.js:5394:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///Users/administrator/Downloads/nodejs/d3.js:7697:32)
    at d3_Map.<anonymous> (file:///Users/administrator/Downloads/nodejs/d3.js:7858:31)
    at d3_Map.d3_class.forEach (file:///Users/administrator/Downloads/nodejs/d3.js:271:13)
    at start (file:///Users/administrator/Downloads/nodejs/d3.js:7857:28)
    at Object.callback (file:///Users/administrator/Downloads/nodejs/d3.js:7851:38)
    at d3_timer_mark (file:///Users/administrator/Downloads/nodejs/d3.js:2075:80)
    at d3_timer_step [as _onTimeout] (file:///Users/administrator/Downloads/nodejs/d3.js:2048:15)
```

Any help with this issue would be great.

Comment: `file://"+__dirname+"/nv.d3.min.js"` you missed a `"` at the beginning?

Comment: same Issue still exists.any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [D3 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767005/d3-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you remove the `transition().duration(500)` call in your code, this is I think useless on server side (it is executed on the server, not the client, so the user won't see the transition) and your stack trace refers to the transition effect so it might fix your issue.

(I had the same issue and removing my transitions fixed it).